# Logical flow in tic-tac-toe issue

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a tic-tac-toe game. Not sure what the convention is, but I used 1 for X and 4 for O, since then a sum of 3 on a column, row, or diagonal will mean a win for X, and a sum of 12 will mean a win for O, and that combination cannot be reached in a non-winning scenario. Similarly, if all rows, columns, and diagonals equal 1,1,4 or 1,4,4 (i.e. 6 or 9) then the game is a draw.

The rest of the game works fine, except for the win conditions:

```
#if a row, column, or diagonal sums to 3, you win, if 12, they win 
#a number 1 = X, a number 4 = O
if (    row1 == 3
    or  row2 == 3
    or  row3 == 3
    or  col1 == 3
    or  col2 == 3
    or  col3 == 3
    or  dia1 == 3
    or  dia2 == 3
    ):
    endCondition = True
    whoWon = "You won!"

if (    row1 == 12
    or  row2 == 12
    or  row3 == 12
    or  col1 == 12
    or  col2 == 12
    or  col3 == 12
    or  dia1 == 12
    or  dia2 == 12
    ):
    endCondition = True
    whoWon = "You lost! Computer wins."

#if that was the last spot, then it is a draw
#a losing row is either 1,1,4 or 1,4,4 which equal six and 9 respectively
if (row1 and row2 and row3 and col1 and col2 and col3 and dia1 and dia2) == (6 or 9):
    endCondition = True
    whoWon = "No one. It was a draw."
```

Any help? I know it's a simple mistake somewhere.

Comment: `(row1 and row2 and row3 and col1 and col2 and col3 and dia1 and dia2) == (6 or 9)` What could that possibly mean?

Comment: _I used 1 for X and 4 for Y_  what is Y?

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with the you-won or computer-won code.  I assume the problem is wherever you compute the values for `row1`, `row2` etc.

Comment: Using artificial values that sum to unique results (1+1+1 = 3, 4+4+4 = 12) is kind of clever, but I think it unnecessarily complicates the code.  Just use 1 and 0, and then check if the same value is present throughout a row or column.  i.e. instead of saying `if row[0] + row[1] + row[2] == 3`, say `if row[0] == row[1] == row[2]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (row1 and row2 and row3 and col1 and col2 and col3 and dia1 and dia2) == (6 or 9):
```

This is not the proper syntax for checking multiple values against multiple other values. `(6 or 9)` will always evaluate to `9`. `(row1 and row2 and ... and dia2)` will evaluate to either 0 if any of the values are 0; or the value of `dia2` if none of the values are 0. So the conditional will incorrectly evaluate to False if the board is full and `dia2` is something other than 9.

Instead, try:

```
if all(x == 6 or x == 9 for x in (row1, row2, row3, col1, col2, col3, dia1, dia2)):
```